# Lightning 2.6.4 is unavailable in Thunderbird 24.3

Tags: thunderbird, lightning, thunderbird-lightning

I have uninstalled and re-installed lightning 2.6.4 - and the options are there but are grayed out.  It is not disabled.  I have a combination of local and google calendars.  Anyone know what is going on?  I googled this and could not find anything, only way-old versions of both software...

Thanks

Comment: A little hard to figure out what the problem is without more information. Could you check the Error Console? What platform are you on? If its Linux, is this a stock Thunderbird from mozilla.org, or the one installed by your distro?

Comment: wow I didn't know there was an error console.  I'm running Windows Vista currently.  here are the errors I'm getting on startup:

Comment: Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Thunderbird/chrome.manifest'.
Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Thunderbird/extensions/%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D/chrome.manifest'.
While creating services from category 'profile-after-change', could not create service for entry 'Disk Space Watcher Service', contract ID '@mozilla.org/toolkit/disk-space-watcher;1'
AddressbooksSynchronizer 1.0.10 appName=Thunderbird appVersion=24.3.0
Timestamp: 2/23/2014 7:22:07 AM

Comment: and then quite a few of these:

Comment: Warning: Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead.
Source File: resource://calendar/modules/calXMLUtils.jsm
Line: 32

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer, as it might be something close to a solution. You mentioned this:

```
Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Thunderbird/chrome.manifest'.
```

This looks to me like Thunderbird is corrupted. Could you try uninstalling and reinstalling Thunderbird?